# android - Send data to a specific app with intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am passing a RTMP video URL to the MX Player app. But I need to force start MX Player when the intent is started instead the user chooses the MX Player manually.
I tried this:

```
i=getPackageManager().
getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad");
i.setData(Uri.parse("MY_URL"));
startActivity(i);
```

When I run this MX Player force closes.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What if the user does not want to use MX Player? Beyond that, what makes you think that `getLaunchIntentForPackage()` is going to give you something that knows how to handle your URL? When you contacted the MX Player developers to ask them about how to work specifically with their app, what did they tell you?

Comment: first of all RTMP links are played only by MX Player and VLC media player. I have specfied in my app to my users to install MX player.

Comment: I haven't contacted the MX Player developers............... if u know any other method to do this ... it will be helpful

Comment: "RTMP links are played only by MX Player and VLC media player" -- there would appear to be [many apps on the Play Store that claim to support RTMP](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=rtmp&c=apps). "I have specfied in my app to my users to install MX player" -- users can do whatever they want. "I haven't contacted the MX Player developers" -- then please do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. This will work for sure:

```
i.setPackage("com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad");
i.setData(URI);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this MX player API

here is sample

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
    intent .setPackage("com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad");
    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("http://host:port/playlist.m3u8");  
    intent.setDataAndType( videoUri, "application/x-mpegURL" );
             intent.setPackage( "com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro" );
         startActivity( intent );
```

[full API doc.](https://sites.google.com/site/mxvpen/api)